# How can I find most frequent combinations of numbers in a list?

Tags: algorithm

Imagine you have a list of numbers (or letters), such as

> 1177783777297461145777267337774652113777236237118777

I want to find the most frequent combinations of numbers in this list:

for 1-digit-long combinations - it is the most frequent number in this list

for 2-digit-long combinations - probably '11'

for 3-digits-long combinations - probably '777' etc

Is there some special algorythm for such a tasks?

UPDATE
Well, by myself I have coded the following (Java). Looks like execution time is proportional to data size multiplied by pattern size:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int DATA_SIZE = 10000;
    int[] data = new int[DATA_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (int) (10 * Math.random()) % 10;
        System.out.print(data[i]);
    }

    int[] pattern1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
    int[] pattern2 = new int[]{7, 7, 7};
    int[] pattern3 = new int[]{7, 7};

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(match(data, pattern1));
    System.out.println(match(data, pattern2));
    System.out.println(match(data, pattern3));
}

static int match(int[] data, int[] pattern)
{
    int matches = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < data.length)
    {
        matches = isEqual(data, i, pattern) ? matches + 1 : matches;
        i++;
    }
    return matches;
}

static boolean isEqual(int[] a, int startIndex, int[] a2)
{
    if (a == a2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (a == null || a2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[startIndex + i] != a2[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: did you even try solving it by yourself before posting on SO?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Guys, yes I know the simplest way - just iterating through the array and storing the most frequent combinations in some map with pattern as a key, and counter as a value, but probably there are better approaches; as far as I understand this is a kind of a typical data mining task

Comment: Your first matching solution should have reasonable average running time for big alphabets and random texts. However, in your case the alphabet is of size 10, and you expect many string repetitions. I would use a smarter algorithm (e.g. KMP, which is linear in worst case). However, I don't see how the reduction to specific pattern matching helps you with the original problem. It will result in a terrible time complexity, because you have to repeat it for all lengths and all sub-sequences of this length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the largest number of repeats of a sequence of length at least k in a string of length n, you can build a suffix tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) in linear time, then find the node that has the most children that describes sequences of length k (or more) from the root.

Overall, this is linear time in the length of the input string.

For small k, you're better off with a naive algorithm:

```
from collections import Counter

def input(s, k):
    c = Counter()
    for i in xrange(len(s) - k):
        c[s[i : i + k]] += 1
    return c.most_common(1)[0][0]


for k in xrange(1, 4):
    print input('1177783777297461145777267337774652113777236237118777', k)
```

Comment: Regarding the interesting suffix tree solution - maybe more details are needed. I understand it this way: 1) construct a suffix tree with counts in leaf nodes 2) sum up node counts and propagate them up the tree, so that every node has the total number of times its corresponding substring appeared in the text. 3) Scan the tree and find best results per depth k=1..n.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in quadratic time, though I'm curious about faster approaches. The idea is iterating over the possible length values k=1..N, and on each iteration loop through the string to find the most frequent sequence of length k.

The inner loop can use a hashtable for counting the frequencies efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go through array mantaining the variable with most  frequent combination already found and auxillary hash table where keys are searching patterns and values are number of occurences in your input data. When you find next pattern, increment the value in hash table and if necessary the value of current most frequent combination.

Comment: @Khay Why? I suggested just he same as Ryal Shneider but for fixed length of pattern (so for one iteration of his solution) My approach is O(N)

Comment: Although I think it's O(Nk) since hash computations are O(k).

Comment: @Anonymous: I think that with a linear preprocess, and a careful choice of a hash function (where you can "undo" the first character) you can compute the hash code in constant time during the loop.

Comment: @EyalSchneider Yes, agreed, using a rolling hash can get you to O(1) for the hash. But you still need to insert into the hashtable, which means you need to check the substring to see if you're inserting the same value as before or a different one, which is still O(k). I think there's an extra trick needed to get down to O(N)...

Answer (score -4):

REGEX - thats the solution to your problem with great efficiency

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

check this it will help you . If you still cant get through lemme know ,ill help

Comment: Can you add details about how you can use regular expressions to solve this problem? I don't see it myself, since I've no idea how to express the idea of "most common substring" using a regexp.

Comment: well who suggested this answer as unuseful ,please show me ur good name and tell me your smart reason as this answer being not useful ,da

Comment: If you can explain in your answer how to solve the problem using regexps, then I'll change my downvote into an upvote. I don't think the answer currently provides enough detail to be useful.